# How do I make module.id work with SystemJS/Angular 2?

Tags: angular, systemjs

For example, I just want this to work:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-cmp',
    moduleId: module.id,,
    templateUrl: 'myCmp.html'
})
```

This way I can just reference the html file in the same folder as the component, without special paths like './src/app/myCmp.html' relative to the root __dirname (the app uses Electron and Angular)

Is there some special configuration I need to do with SystemJS for the app and tests, to make module.id and simple template paths like the above 'myCmp.html' work?

Comment: Can you please post your `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Read [this blog](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html). It gives a couple of options and shows you some examples of bad procedures (and why) and shows you some good examples, and explains how they work (quite in depth).

You should be able to find your specific answer in this blog. There are even multiple ways discussed.